# Как исключить использования глобальной переменной

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Ребят, как мне исключить  глобальную переменную `summ` которая принимает значение введенное пользователем, а в дальнейшем, но уже в другой функции эту переменную перемножить.

Несколько дней изучаю `bot.register_next_step_handler` и не могу понять как это значение передавать из функции в функцию.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def any_msg(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    callback_button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рассчитать стоимость", callback_data="summa")
    keyboard.add(callback_button1)
    bot.reply_to(message," Привет, " + message.from_user.first_name)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Какой то текст",reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "summa")
def replenish_balans(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    time.sleep(1)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Ведите кол-во мешков в шт:\nМинимальная сумма заказа 50 шт ", parse_mode='HTML')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, take_money)


def take_money(message: types.Message):
    *global summ
    summ=message.text*
    # проверка, является ли введенный юзером текст числом (только int)
    if (message.text.isdigit()) and summ >= "50":
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Оплатить при получении", callback_data="nal"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Банковская карта", callback_data="karta"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="К выбору города", callback_data="1"))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Для заказа:\n <b>{summ} мешков </b>\n Выберите способ оплаты :",
                         reply_markup=markup, parse_mode='HTML')



    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "<b>Некорректный ввод\n➖➖➖➖\n‼️Введите количество в шт\n➖➖➖➖\n"
                                          "‼Минимальная сумма заказа 50 шт</b>", parse_mode='HTML')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, take_money)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "nal")
def choise_service(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    time.sleep(2)
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Sberbank", url='https://sberbank.ru')
    )
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,message_id=call.message.message_id,text=" Для заказа  "  <b>" + summ +" мешков </b>  оплатите:\n➖➖➖➖\n""<b>"**(ТУТ МНЕ НАДО ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ summ умножить цену....  + summ*425 + " рублей**) </b>\n на <b>Карту сбербанка</b> " \
     "\n➖➖➖➖\n<code>4275 8585 8585 8525</code>,
      reply_markup=markup, parse_mode='HTML')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё описал внутри кода

```
def take_money(message: types.Message):
    # 1) уберите лишние скобки в условии, это питон а не джс
    # 2) сравнение summ >= "50" очень плохое,
    # высока вероятность неправильного срабатывания
    # лучше сделайте его отдельно и заодно приведите к инту

    def validate(value: str) -> bool:
        if value.isdigit():
            if int(value) >= 50:
                return True
        return False

    if validate(message.text):
        # row_width = 1 стоит по-умолчанию
        # и собстенно к вопросу. Так как вы передаете в колбек то register_next_step_handler
        # вам не подойдет, но у вас по факту просто небольшое число,
        # я бы сделал так, запихнул число в колбек дату, а потом парсил
        # саму колбек дату
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
            # как видишь я сделал слудющее
            # сделал префикс payment и разделил двоеточиями типо оплаты и количество
            # дальше смотри колбек хандлер ниже
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Оплатить при получении", callback_data=f"payment:nal:{message.text}"),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Банковская карта", callback_data=f"payment:karta:{message.text}"),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="К выбору города", callback_data="1"))
        bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            f"Для заказа:\n <b>{message.text} мешков </b>\n Выберите способ оплаты :",
            reply_markup=markup,
            parse_mode='HTML')

    else:
        # не вижу смысла в слипе, так как это стопорит и без
        # того синхронного бота
        # time.sleep(1)
        bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            "<b>Некорректный ввод\n➖➖➖➖\n‼️Введите количество в шт\n➖➖➖➖\n"
            "‼Минимальная сумма заказа 50 шт</b>",
            parse_mode='HTML')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, take_money)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith("payment"))
def choise_service(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    # ты забыл сделать ансвер колбека, 
    # он делает так чтобы "часики" на кнопке пропали
    bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
    # тоже не понимаю зачем
    # time.sleep(2)
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Sberbank", url='https://sberbank.ru'))
    # сейчас получаем три вещи, 
    # префикс - payment он нам не нужен, но мы распаковываем, так что пусть валяется
    # тип оплаты nal или karta
    # ну и нашу сумму но они все строки, не забывай об этом
    prefix, type_payment, summa = call.data.split(":")
    bot.edit_message_text(
        chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
        message_id=call.message.message_id,
        # используй лучше f-строки ибо то что ты кинул нерабочий код вообще. 
        # Синтаксическая ошибка все такое
        text=f"Для заказа<b> {summa} мешков</b> оплатите:\n➖➖➖➖\n"
             f"<b>{int(summa) * 415} рублей</b>\n"
             f"на<b>Карту сбербанка</b>\n➖➖➖➖\n"
             f"<code>4275 8585 8585 8525</code>",
        reply_markup=markup, 
        parse_mode='HTML')
```

Comment: # я бы сделал так, запихнул число в колбек дату, а потом парсил -хорошая идея есть чему учиться)

Comment: if message.text.isdigit():    
        if int(message.text) >= 50:
В таком случае при вводе меньшего колличества, функция встает и не выдает ошибку с последующим циклом повтора ввода!, исправил добавлением еще одного else: в блоке if int(message.text) >= 50: такой вариант допустим?

Comment: Увы недопустим, разобрался почему! как тогда оптимизировать эти 2 условия?

Comment: Пользуясь случаем задам еще вопрос с вашего позволения! При оплате наличными я хочу предоставить скидку 5%. Как мне сделать на выходе {int(summa)*95/100}чтоб это было int а не float?

Comment: @Vihr2021 Первый вопрос пофиксил, насчет скидки, просто перед выводом приведите еще раз к int всё выражение

Comment: Полчаса вникаю что вы сделали. Я правильно понял что в случае   if int(value) >= 500:  и if value.isdigit(): есть ошибка то есть True, он запускает else, в ином случае  возвращает false и запускает def validate?

Comment: @Vihr2021 всмысле? Я просто запускаю функцию валидации передаю в неё месседж текст, проверяю является ли оно числом, а потом больше ли оно 50, если да True, если ни одно не выполнилось то False. В итоге строка `if validate(message.text):` стает либо `if False:` либо `if True:`. Если же условие правдивое то все ок, если нет запускается елсе

Comment: @Vihr2021 в целом строку `return False` можно убрать, но оставил для лучшего понимания

Comment: Спасибо за подробное разъяснение очень помогаете вникнуть в этот увлекательный процесс))) Вот только как вы и посоветовали перед выводом повторно перевожу в Int , но все равно выдает дробь(text=f"Для пополнения счета на <b> {(summa)} руб</b> оплатите:\n➖➖➖➖\n"
             f" <b>{int(summa)*95/100} рублей</b>

Comment: `{int(int(summa)*95/100)} `

Comment: Вопрос отпал! А еще говорят Пайтогн умный)) Ему по 2 раза оказывается нужно повторять что сделать{int(int(summa)*0.95)})))

Comment: @Vihr2021 если ответ вам подошёл нажмите на галочку слева от ответа и стрелочку вверх

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)